# Functions such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(f(\frac{x}{n})+f(\frac{2x}{n})+...+f(\frac{nx}{n}))$=$f(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to find all $f(x)$ continuous function s that :

$\ \lim_{n\to\infty}$$\frac{1}{n}(f(\frac{x}{n})$+$f(\frac{2x}{n})$+...+$f(\frac{nx}{n}))$=$f(x)$

It looks similar to Riemann integral, but I'm not sure how to show that.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x>0$ consider the interval $[0,x]. $. Then $\{\frac{jx}{n}: j=0,...,n\}$ is a partition of this interval, hence

$$\frac{x}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\bigg(\frac {kx}n\bigg) \to  \int_0^x f(t) dt.$$

Therefore
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t) dt.$$

This shows that $f$ is differentiable  for $x>0$ and (your turn !) $f'(x)=0$.

Hence, $f$ is constant .

Comment: so what is my $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Should that be $f(x)=\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t) dt$, so that any constant function $f(x)=c$ is a solution ?

Comment: Ooops, you are right. An edit will follow.

Comment: why 1/x ? @Fred

Comment: We have $\frac{x}{n}(f(\frac{x}{n})+...+\frac{nx}{n}) \to  \int_0^x f(t) dt$ hence $f(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(f(\frac{x}{n})+...+\frac{nx}{n})=\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t) dt$

Comment: sorry but I still don't understand why 1/x @Fred

Comment: If $x \ne 0$ and $xa_n  \to a$, then $a_n \to \frac{1}{x}a$.

Comment: ok, thanks !
why is $f'(x)$=0 ?

Comment: We have $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t) dt$. Now differentiate and look what happens !

Comment: I got that $f'(x)$=$f(x)$ 
Is that right ? @Fred

Comment: No. With the quotient rule we get $f'(x)= \frac{f(x)x-\int_0^x f(t) dt}{x^2}= \frac{f(x)x-xf(x)}{x^2}=0$

Comment: thank you !!!! @Fred

Comment: I got mistake..